# Multiple html tags issue in Azure hosted MVC6 project

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

My MVC 6 project hosted in Azure is resulting in multiple HTML tags. The html is getting rendered completely with a duplicate of HTML, Head, Body and internal tags within body again.

This works fine in local, but not on Azure. Any pointers to debug the issue will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have any javascript in the page that gets data from a service and displays it? sometimes a failed api request results in a default page route being returned (ie: the api fail returns the html of the parent page which then gets added to the DOM, rather than the expected api response). F12 in the browser - check the console for errors.

Comment: azure hosting has nothing to do with multiple rendering. Azure project ( cloud service project ) usually is used just to start webrole. nothing else. may be you should try looking at code you wrote in MVC.